# Is there a GUI alternative to GParted?

Tags: software-rec, partition

GParted 0.7.0 is less than ideal, so am looking for something else. Is there a credible alternative?

[**update**] The [two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7051/688) [issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7028/688) I was having had nothing to do with GParted.

Comment: What are you looking for that GParted doesn't have?

Comment: ^^ This. GParted is the default for partition editing tasks on Linux. I would not know what is not 'credible' so, pray tell, what bothers you about it?

Comment: Did you find that this was related to your USB stick problem (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7028/how-to-get-my-usb-stick-to-auto-mount)? If so would you mind updating this question? It sounds more like a distribution-related (automounter) problem than a problem with gparted.

Comment: @ith You are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless something changed recently GParted is de facto standard tool. The only viable alternative are partially CLI partially GUI tools like cfdisk.

Answer (score 3):

partitionmanager is a KDE/Qt gui using the same libs GParted uses. (afaik)
It is almost feature-equivalent.

As of now, it lacks support for setting file system labels on some file systems, where GParted can set them just fine.(eg. fat32)
Other than that, it works just like GParted.

Link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/partitionman/