# How to get my USB stick to auto-mount?

Tags: gnome, automounting

I used to be able to have my USB stick auto-mount when I plugged it in, on my GNOME desktop. After some fiddling with my system, it doesn't happen anymore. I now have to resort to doing this using the command line.

Here's the Window that appears when I stick it in:

[image]

Here's the end of `dmesg` output:

```
[20500.548090] usb 2-3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 6
[20500.703390] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=8564, idProduct=1000
[20500.703399] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[20500.703406] usb 2-3: Product: Mass Storage Device
[20500.703411] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: JetFlash
[20500.703416] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 64V6ZJ34LRL69IU1
[20500.703868] usb 2-3: selecting invalid altsetting 1
[20500.704828] scsi8 : usb-storage 2-3:1.0
[20502.122302] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JetFlash Transcend 8GB    1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[20502.123693] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[20502.125043] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 15826944 512-byte logical blocks: (8.10 GB/7.54 GiB)
[20502.125774] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[20502.125782] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[20502.125789] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[20502.132333] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[20502.133529]  sdb: sdb1
[20502.135252] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[20502.135257] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[20502.658377] UDF-fs: No anchor found
[20502.658380] UDF-fs: Rescanning with blocksize 2048
[20502.682376] UDF-fs: No anchor found
[20502.682379] UDF-fs: No partition found (1)
[20502.738750] ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.
```

Comment: This can be done in a number of ways. Which one is preferred/best/recommended/easiest is distribution-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went and tried mounting the USB stick with `pmount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/blah` and it it gives a more useful message than the GUI dialogue:

```
Warning: device /dev/sdb1 is already handled by /etc/fstab, supplied label is ignored
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

This led me to find that "**/etc/fstab**" actually has an entry for /dev/sdb1:

```
/dev/sdb1       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

The reason for this is that my stick was actually attached while installing Debian Squeeze, and so got automatically added in there. That's what will happen when you install from the same stick, and now I'm curious how others avoid this problematic situation.

Comment: That was my first guess, since it seems to be taken as a cdrom drive.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your USB stick has a hidden partiton that acts as a CD-ROM drive.  You might need to look for a Windows utility from the manufacturer that can remove that, unfortunately.