# How to re-mount a USB stick after unmounting from Nautilus without disconnecting it?

Tags: linux, usb, mount, usb-drive

I find that in order to re-mount a USB stick, I have to physically disconnect it, and then re-connect it. How can I do this without such tiring physical action?

Comment: The USB device is logically disconnected (there should be a message to that effect your kernel logs). It won't have a `/dev` entry any more, and IIRC won't show up in `lsusb` either. I don't know if there's a way to reconnect it.

Comment: This question is very similar to: https://superuser.com/questions/1163375/linux-cant-format-nor-access-a-detected-usb-key-no-medium-found

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From my experience in Ubuntu, when you "eject" a USB stick from within Nautilus, the device actually disappears from the system. I'm not sure why this is, but neither Nautilus nor the command line can get it back. I guess the logic is that once you eject a USB stick you don't want it back, but are going to disconnect it.

The way I work around this (when needed), is by using `umount` instead of Nautilus. You could also just call `sync` to flush the filesystem buffers to the disk.

Just found a thread which has more info : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1477247

So basically either a) Rebuild nautilus from source without that patch (and keep it up to date when you update your system...) or b) use another file manager (at least when unmounting ^^).

Comment: Check `/dev/disk/by-id` and see if the device is truly gone.  I'll bet it's not, and can be remounted from there with a `mount` command.

Comment: @ultrasawblade `/dev/disk/by-id` contains *symlinks* to device files in `/dev`, for example `/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Kingston_DT_100_G2_001CC0C60DBDFC90D32923CE-0:0 -> ../../sdb`. When the device is gone after `udisks --eject` (which I assume happens here), the symlink is stale and cannot be used for re-mounting.

Comment: @LawrenceC It seemed ultrasawblade was right. I got `mount: /mnt: no medium found on /dev/sdc` But as noted in the answer by sdaau, this works: `sudo eject -t /dev/sdc`

Comment: Thanks! Note there is an "unmount" option in the *launcher* in 22.04 (or at least Pop!OS 22.04), so you don't need a whole new file manager or a re-built Nautilus.

Answer (score 22):

This is the behavior I have on my Ubuntu Lucid system:

When I plug in my USB flash/thumbdrive which has two partitions, the system reports:

```
$ ls /dev/sdb*
/dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1  /dev/sdb2

$ udisks --show-info /dev/sdb | grep -A2 'partition table\|by-id'
    by-id:                     /dev/disk/by-id/usb-takeMS_USB_Mini_AA07013000010057-0:0
    by-path:                   /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
  detected at:                 Mon 29 Apr 2013 02:16:50 PM CEST
--
  partition table:
    scheme:                    mbr
    count:                     2

$ udisks --show-info /dev/sdb1 | grep -A2 'partition table\|by-id'
    by-id:                     /dev/disk/by-id/usb-takeMS_USB_Mini_AA07013000010057-0:0-part1
    by-id:                     /dev/disk/by-uuid/581E-EE0B
    by-path:                   /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1
  detected at:                 Mon 29 Apr 2013 04:24:25 PM CEST

$ udisks --show-info /dev/sdb2 | grep -A2 'partition table\|by-id'
    by-id:                     /dev/disk/by-id/usb-takeMS_USB_Mini_AA07013000010057-0:0-part2
    by-id:                     /dev/disk/by-uuid/4A0E-A166
    by-path:                   /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part2
  detected at:                 Mon 29 Apr 2013 04:24:25 PM CEST

$ udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sdb | grep DEVPATH
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/host13/target13:0:0/13:0:0:0/block/sdb    
$ udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sdb1 | grep DEVPATH
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/host13/target13:0:0/13:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1
$ udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sdb2 | grep DEVPATH
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/host13/target13:0:0/13:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb2
$ sudo partprobe /dev/sdb
$
```

So, only partitions have `/dev/disk/by-uuid`; while both disk and partitions have (different) `/dev/disk/by-id`.

Now, if I left-click on either of the partition entries in the Disk Mounter applet in the Gnome2 desktop in Lucid, I get only two entries: "Open" or "Eject" (as mentioned in the [[SOLVED] How do you remount a usb drive with nautilus in lynx?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1477247), from [@Thomas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7108/8069)' answer, referring to a [16_hide_unmount.patch](http://trac.lliurex.net/leia/browser/mods-features/trunk/nautilus/debian/patches/16_hide_unmount.patch)). Also, `palimpsest` here shows two partitions for the disk.

When I click on the Eject on either one of the partitions - they both dissapear; at this point, `palimpsest` shows the disk, but no partitions, and a "No medium found" message instead; also:

```
$ ls /dev/sdb*
/dev/sdb

$ udisks --show-info /dev/sdb | grep -A2 'partition table\|by-id'
    by-id:                     /dev/disk/by-id/usb-takeMS_USB_Mini_AA07013000010057-0:0
    by-path:                   /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
  detected at:                 Mon 29 Apr 2013 02:16:50 PM CEST

$ udisks --show-info /dev/sdb1 | grep -A2 'partition table\|by-id'
$

$ udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sdb | grep DEVPATH
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/host13/target13:0:0/13:0:0:0/block/sdb
$ udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sdb1 | grep DEVPATH
device node not found

$ sudo partprobe /dev/sdb
Error: Error opening /dev/sdb: No medium found
```

So, as mentioned in comment by [@ultrasawblade](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7051/how-to-re-mount-a-usb-stick-after-unmounting-from-nautilus-without-disconnecting#comment8915_7108), indeed the disk is there, but not the partitions - although, I think I'd need the partitions *as devices*, in order to `mount`.

Also, the same behavior as left-click+"Eject" in desktop GUI, I can get in terminal with `sudo eject /dev/sdb`. Note that one can also open `palimpsest`, from there click on each of the two partitions, and click "Unmount Volume" - at that point, the icons for the partitions will *still* be shown in Disk Mounter applet, but will be noted as unmounted; and then one can do `sudo udisks --detach /dev/sdb`: this makes the icons disappear from Disk Mounter applet - but also the `/dev/sdb` device will not be present on the system anymore (however, `lsusb` will still show the device)!

After searching quite a bit for the answer (tried stuff from `udevadm monitor --environment` during plug and unplug, with replicating all actions via `udevadm trigger`, to looking into what the `BLKRRPART` ioctl does), without any success - I finally stumbled upon [How To Remount A USB Stick Without Removing And Reinserting - Ubuntu/Debian](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/09/how-to-remount-usb-stick-without.html), which has the answer:

```
sudo eject -t /dev/sdb
```

After this command is ran - the two partitions appear again in Disk Mounter applet - without unplugging/re-plugging the USB key!! This is all the stranger, because if you read `man eject`:

```
   -t   With  this  option the drive is given a CD-ROM tray close command.
        Not all devices support this command.
```

... you'd never expect it's applicable to USB Flash/Thumb drive! (And I even tried looking into [sys-utils/eject.c](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux/+/v2.22-rc1/sys-utils/eject.c), and I cannot see anything obvious `:)` )

Of course, if `sudo udisks --detach /dev/sdb` has been ran previously, then `/dev/sdb` won't exist, so `eject -t /dev/sdb` will fail with `eject: unable to find or open device for: '/dev/sdb'`. In that case, the USB power cycle as noted in [#7457 How to reconnect a logically disconnected USB device?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7412/how-to-reconnect-a-logically-disconnected-usb-device/7457#7457) helped me recover:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo suspend > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/power/level'
$ sudo sh -c 'echo auto > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/power/level'
```

This made the partitions' icons show again in Disk Mounter applet, directly as mounted; to find the right address, try while the disk is mounted:

```
$ udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/sdb | grep "looking\|busnum\|devnum" | grep -B1 'busnum\|devnum'
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-2':
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="13"
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1':
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"

# the first (.../usb1/1-2) should be the right one, check bus/devnum:
$ lsusb -s 1:13
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 090c:1000 Feiya Technology Corp. Flash Drive

# looks good; check for symlinks in `sys/bus/usb/devices` as per "parent device" .../usb1/1-2
$ ls -la /sys/bus/usb/devices/ | grep "usb1/1-2"
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2013-04-29 17:17 1-2 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2013-04-29 17:21 1-2:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0

# so it should be /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2; check if it has power/level:
$ ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/power/level 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/power/level
```

Comment: tl;dr: The command to "insert" an ejected USB drive again is `eject -t /dev/<DEVICE>`.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 9):

On Debian based systems, at least, you should be able to do this:

1. figure out what the drive letter should be... I'm gong to say /dev/sdb here for the example.
2. Double eject the 'would be' drive letter to effectively power the device back on.
3. Profit!

This works because... magic.

```
# determine 'would be drive letter'
lsblk
# do magic
eject /dev/sdb; sleep 1; eject -t /dev/sdb
```

Comment: This answer is pretty short and low on details, but it does seem to do the trick. I actually used `eject -t` without the initial `eject` and `sleep` and it worked. I notice that even though my drive was mounted as /dev/sdb1 (note the partition number), ejecting /dev/sdb (whole disk) was necessary.

Comment: This sort of worked for me, so thank you! The device showed back up on some other processes I needed, but I was not able to remount it through the GUI in the convenient way.