# How to logically eject/disconnect & reattach a usb device (dongle)?

Tags: linux, usb, usb-device

We've bought a commercial application who just work only if their dongle usb is connected to the server. However sometimes the application can not recognize the dongle, so it doesn't work, but if someone eject the dongle physically from USB port and attach it again it will recognize and work fine.

There are 43 modules loaded on the server and attach/eject the dongle does not increase/decrease number of modules.

Also I have *usbmon0*, *usbmon1* and *usbmon2* files in */dev*  before/after eject/attach the dongle and  number of files in */dev* will not change before/after eject/attach the dongle.

*journalctl -f* command after ejecting the dongle:

```
Jan 19 18:10:28 iwr kernel: usb 2-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
```

*journalctl -f* command after attaching the dongle:

```
Jan 19 18:11:11 iwr kernel: usb 2-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using uhci_hcd
Jan 19 18:11:11 iwr kernel: usb 2-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=c580
Jan 19 18:11:11 iwr kernel: usb 2-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 19 18:11:11 iwr kernel: usb 2-2.1: Product: HID UNIKEY
Jan 19 18:11:11 iwr kernel: usb 2-2.1: Manufacturer: OEM
Jan 19 18:11:11 iwr kernel: usbhid 2-2.1:1.0: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
```

Can I eject and then attach it logically? (issue a command, remove a module, etc.)

Comment: Please check if [any of those solutions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7412/how-to-reconnect-a-logically-disconnected-usb-device) work.

Comment: Thanks TNW for replying, I tried them but none of them worked for me. `echo 2-2.1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-2.1/driver/unbind` worked for eject and `echo 2-2.1 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Many answers found on the Internet (including those in TNW's comment) rely on `/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-2/power/level` or `/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-2/power/control` which are both deprecated since 2.6.something kernel. For newer kernels, the [suggested procedure](https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/) is to unbind and rebind its driver, which usually results in a power cycle:

```
# Find out which driver to unbind
tree /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-2.1 | grep driver
|-- driver -> ../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/whatever

# Unbind the driver
echo 2-2.1 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/whatever/unbind

# Rebind the driver
echo 2-2.1 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/whatever/bind
```

Comment: Thanks dear Dmitry. As Dmitry said, `/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-2/power/level` and `/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-2/power/control` does not work (level and control files do not exist) because the kernel version is 3.10.0 . but `echo 2-2.1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-2.1/driver/unbind` worked for eject and `echo 2-2.1 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind` worked for attach.

Comment: I'm glad that helped, and thanks for reporting back!

Comment: How do you identify the device number when you have many devices?

Comment: @djsmiley2k usually by looking at vendor ID and device ID of each USB device

Comment: I found it in dmesg, at the start of the logged message ;D - I'm so blind! :)