# Is possible to re-add a removed iommu device?

Tags: pci-passthrough, iommu

I use pci passthrough.
Unfortunately my card is sharing the same irq of an usb controller.
I use this procedure:

Find the sharing irq, in my case return 21
    lspci -s 00:05:00 -vvv

Find the irq

```
cat /proc/interrupts|grep 21:
```

Return me usb2

So search usb2

```
find  /sys/devices/pci0000\:00/0000\:00\:* -iname usb2
```

Return me pci address, so I go to address
and remove the usb2 hub-slot

```
cd /sys/devices/pci0000\:00/0000\:00\:13.2/
echo -n 1 > remove
```

The question is: how to read the usb2 slot?

If you have a question like: why do you remove the slot?
The answer is: my pci card is really old(1999!) and doesn't share
the irq, so if you run a vm with this card the interrupt must be unique,
otherwise qemu/libvirt gives an error.

Comment: Maybe one of the methods on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7412/how-to-reconnect-a-logically-disconnected-usb-device can be adapted to your case.