# How to power on an external hard-drive after powering it off?

Tags: mount, external-hdd, udisks

When I "safely remove" an external hard-drive from my file-manager (Thunar), the whole hard-drive is powered off and disappears from `/dev`. Therefore, I guess that under the hood, this is done by calling `udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdX` which has the same effect.

I thought it should somehow be possible to bring the device up again. After having read https://stackoverflow.com/a/12675749, I thought that powering off is maybe done by writing to `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/control`, but the sysfs seems to remain untouched.

So, how is it possible to power-on an external device again after powering it off with udisksctl? To me, it is annoying that I can not re-mount a partition after unmounting it from the file manager.

Comment: The unbind/rebind approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18098075/634919) does work.  However, it has the undesirable side-effect of resetting all other devices on that USB controller.  This is bad if you have, say, another USB hard drive that you are accessing - you get I/O errors and an unwanted remount read-only.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74066/366177). It has many useful information which might be useful to you.

Comment: At some risk of asking the obvious, is unplugging/re-plugging in the external device an option? Or if there is a physical power switch on it, turning that off and back on? The first option is something that, to me, has just become a near-daily "second-nature" kind of thing.

Comment: @Jim that's what I do nearly every day, too. But it remains annoying.

Comment: @Binabik I hear you. Windows is the same if you use the "safe removal" feature.

Comment: All I know is that to make an ESATA device be seen by `lsblk` I do `echo "- - -" | sudo tee /sys/class/scsi_host/host2/scan` (that is, if it's not auto-picked up / detected when plugged in)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Thunar is behaving like `udisksctl power-off`, then it is using [usb_remove_store()](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=253e05724f9230910344357b1142ad8642ff9f5a).

That means Thunar is being misfeature-compatible with Microsoft Windows. You can just use `eject /dev/sdX` from the command line instead to allow hardware to be safely removed. The only difference is that the LED light won't turn off. To un-eject, use `eject -t /dev/sdX`.

Here's a quote from Alan Stern (who actually wrote the Linux kernel code that performs the "remove" option):

> In fact, the "remove" attribute works for any USB device, since all it
>   does is disable the upstream port. But normally it's intended only for
>   mass-storage devices. I was going to say that it's needed only for
>   mass-storage devices, but that's not correct -- it isn't *needed* at
>   all. Its main purpose is to make people who have been conditioned by
>   Windows feel more comfortable, by turning off an LED on the device to
>   indicate that removal is now safe.